# Online hops reference

Tags: hops

Is there any online place to get as much information as possible about hops. For example alpha and beta acids, cohumulone content, aroma progile and any other possibly useful information?

I did my himework and I found this [one](http://www.homebrew4less.com/docs/Hops_Cross-Reference_Chart.html), but it is sometimes vague and lacks lot of information.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Not in particular.  I've compiled one from multiple sources, both paper and digital, for http://brew-journal.com/hops/.

http://homebrewtalk.com/wiki/index.php/Hops is one of the better sources.  https://byo.com/resources/hops too, but poor ui. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_hop_varieties of course has an article that's suprisingly complete, except for the lack of quantitative information.

There's been an explosion in varieties in the last year or so that aren't listed in a lot of places.  zythos, greenburg, Polaris, Ivanhoe, Merkur, Mosaic, Kohatu, &c.

Answer (score 1):

I just bought some rhizomes from freshops.com. While visiting the site before I made my order I noticed that they had lots useful and interesting information. You should check it out!
http://www.freshops.com/

Answer (score 1):

The HopUnion databook is my favorite source.

http://www.hopunion.com/17_HopVarieties.cfm?p3=open